# Automating Excel with Python For Loop Zero Value Issue

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

I am new to coding and trying to automate payroll for my company. I have an excel file with the names, hours worked, and pay scales for my employees. I have imported the excel file and am trying to parse the data, but when encountering an employee that didn't work that week (hours worked = 0) the loop stops. I know it must be some issue with a none vale, but I'm not able to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('payrollvalues.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

start_row = 5
names = []
hour_row = 22
hours =[]

while ws.cell(row=start_row, column=3).value:
    name = ws.cell(row=start_row, column=3).value
    names.append(name)
    start_row += 22 

while ws.cell(row=hour_row, column=11).value:
    hour = ws.cell(row=hour_row, column=11).value
    hours.append(hour)
    hour_row +=22

ws.delete_rows(1, ws.max_row)

for index, name in enumerate(names, start=2):
    ws.cell(row=index, column=1, value=name)

for hour_index, hour in enumerate(hours, start=2):
    ws.cell(row=hour_index, column=2, value=hour)
```

The issue is with the last line, when the value of hours worked on the document is zero. I also converted the file to value only in excel in case there was some formula issue. I have tried adding,

```
if hour == 0:
    print("0")
    continue
```

But it still encounters an issue. I have also tried without the print statement. I know this must be a skill issue, so thank you for the help!

Comment: Please, share a little sample for the `payrollvalues.xlsx` file, so we can actually execute the code and realize what is happening. Really hard to figure out conditionals and loops without even knowing the variable values.

Comment: New to coding and developing [part of] a corporate payroll system?

Comment: @DarkKnight the company is really bare bones and uses timecards done manually,  I'm attempting to take the raw xml data and automate this part a little bit. It isn't a tech position, but figured it would be a project for some experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's maybe an issue in while condition

```
while <condition>:
```

It will only work when condition is True.
For integers (that you put in your condition) value 0 equal to boolean False (try `bool(0)` and `bool(1)`).
Try to use:

```
while cell(...).value is not None:
```

Maybe it will help:)

Comment: Amazing! I knew it was a simple change. I tried adding this to the for loop earlier but didn't know what I was doing. Thank you!